# Android Studio can not import module

Tags: android, android-studio

Error message:

```
Element: class org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyFileImpl 
because: different providers: 
SingleRootFileViewProvider{ 
myVirtualFile=file:///Users/renrenliwangluokeji/Desktop/SDDAndroid/StepDemo2/settings.gradle,
content=VirtualFileContent{size=15}}(69e7355d); 
SingleRootFileViewProvider{ myVirtualFile=file:///Users/renrenliwangluokeji/Desktop/SDDAndroid/StepDemo2/settings.gradle,
content=VirtualFileContent{size=15}}(1efd863f)
```

Comment: add your `gradle` files to the question

Comment: As @WIZARD has told you add the `gradle` file and also explain how or when exactly do you get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like IDE issue, try manually adding

```
include ':app', ':your_module_name'
```

in settings.gradle and sync gradle, hope it helps.

Reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77939622